# Префиксы в именах полей БД

Tags: база-данных, именование

Как правильно называть поля в БД? Например, в таблице `users` назвать поля `user_id`, `user_name` и т.п. или просто `id`, `name`?

Comment: есть небольшой [документ](http://www.sqlstyle.guide/) по стилю sql, можете следовать ему. Там, правда, такие детали не уточнены, но из *Keep the length to a maximum of 30 bytes* и примеров можно сделать вывод, что дублировать не стоит

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Никаких авторитетных источников не знаю, но по своему опыту работы с фреймворками и CMS'ками могу сказать, что нет смысла префикса в полях, так как они уже принадлежат таблице.
Предположим, что у нас есть две таблицы: `student` и `department`, и мы попытаемся достать данные из двух таблиц:

```
SELECT 
    student.student_name, 
    department.department_name 
FROM 
    student, 
    department 
WHERE
    student.department_id = department.department_id
```

Или всe же лучше сделать так?

```
SELECT 
    student.name, 
    department.name 
FROM 
    student, 
    department 
WHERE
    student.department_id = department.id
```

Префикс поля в таблице нужен в том случае, если это ключ на другую таблицу, как, например, в моем случае: `student.department_id`.

Answer (score 2):

В общем, распространяются стандартные правила: ваши поля должны нести смысловую нагрузку. Так, например, если есть таблица пользователей, описывающая их, то `id` и `name` будет достаточно.
Если в таблице встречаются какие-то противоречия, то есть, например, не только `user_id`, но и, скажем, `car_id`, которое связывается с таблицей `car`, то для смысловой нагрузки можно использовать и так, но не обязательно. Или если `user_id` встречается в ещё одной из таблиц и является ключом, то да - тут обязательно.
Называйте так, как велит вам сердце. Начертите БД с табличками на листочке и посмотрите, как оно будет лучше и понятнее. Основное правило тут - ваша БД должна быть понятна другому разработчику, который столкнется с ней.